# Using SQL window function to update values from next rows?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, window-functions, rank

I have a table that has some ranges per each client. I need these ranges to have no overlap (with at least 0.01 diff between max of higher row and min of lower row).

**Example:**

```
| Client | min | max |
|--------|-----|-----|
| A      |   1 | 2.5 |
| A      |   2 | 3.5 |
| A      | 3.5 |   4 |
| B      |   1 |   2 |
| B      |   3 |   5 |
| B      | 4.5 |  10 |
```

I need this data to look like this:

```
| Client | min  | max |
|--------|------|-----|
| A      |    1 | 2.5 |
| A      | 2.51 | 3.5 |
| A      | 3.51 |   4 |
| B      |    1 |   2 |
| B      |    3 |   5 |
| B      | 5.01 |  10 |
```

Do I need to use window function? Appreciate any help.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want a query that returns your values, you can use:

```
select client,
       (case when min < lag(max) over (partition by client order by min)
             then lag(max) over (partition by client order by min) + 0.01
             else min
        end)
from t;
```

Notes:

- `min` and `max` are really bad choices for table names because they are SQL keywords.
- The `0.01` seems rather magical.  I would suggest a different approach where the lower bound is inclusive and the upper bound exclusive.  That way, you won't miss values such as 5.0005.
- If you want to `update` the table, the best method depends on the database you are using.

EDIT:

If you need to reset the `max()` as well, then use a subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (case when max < new_min then new_max = new_min + 0.01 else max end) as new_max
from (select t.*,
             (case when min < lag(max) over (partition by client order by min)
                   then lag(max) over (partition by client order by min) + 0.01
                   else min
              end) as new_min
      from t
     ) t
```

However, this might not work in complicated cases.

Comment: What if I need to also check for each range whether the min is smaller than max. For example, let's say I have min=2.5 and max=2.5. I update min to 2.51 and I need to also update max to 2.52. How can I do that? It seems the lag function performs column by column.

Comment: @aghd . . . I added a simplistic solution.  However, I think you should ask a new question with appropriate sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

consider below

```
select client,
  greatest(min, lag(max, 1, -777) over (partition by client order by min) + 0.01) min,
  greatest(max, min, lag(max, 1, -777) over (partition by client order by min) + 0.01) max
from `project.dataset.table`
```

[image]

Comment: What if I need to also check for each range whether the min is smaller than max for every row as well. For example, let's say I have min=2.5 and max=2.5. I update min to 2.51 and I need to also update max to 2.52. How can I do that? It seems the lag function performs column by column. – aghd 1 hour ago   Delete

Comment: Above should handle it, I think. Have you tried?